# Problem parsing an XLS file with C#

Tags: c#, excel

Ok, let's see if I can make this make sense.

I have a program written that parses an Excel file and it works just fine.  I use the following to get into the file:

```
string FileToConvert = Server.MapPath(".") + "\\App_Data\\CP-ARFJN-FLAG.XLS";
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + FileToConvert + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
//this next line assumes that the file is in default Excel format with Sheet1 as the first sheet name, adjust accordingly
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [CP-ARFJN-FLAG$]", connection);
```

and this works just fine.  But when I try it on the actual file (it is supplied to me by another program) I get this error:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: External table is not in the expected format. at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection) at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open() at wetglobe.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

BUT, this is where I think the problem lies.  If I take that file, and save it with my local Excel, first I get this popup:

> CP-ARFJN-FLAG.XLS may contain features
>   that are not compatible with Text (Tab
>   delimited). Do you want to keep the
>   workbook in this format?
>
> - To Keep this format, which leaves
>     out any incompatible features, click
>     Yes.
> - To preserve the features, click No. 
>     Ten save a copy in the latest Excel
>     format.
> - To see what might be lost, click
>     Help.

If I click No and then save it as the current Excel format, the program will then work fine.

So I am assuming this is saved in some crazy old Excel format?

I suppose my questions would be:

- How can I tell what Excel version
  saved this?
- How can I parse it in its current
  state?
- -or- Can I programatically save it as a newer version?

I hope that is clear... Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like the XLS file generated by your third-party app may not really be in Excel format - it might actually be a tab-delimited text file with an .xls extension.

Try opening it with a text editor and see.

If it is tab delimited, you can ditch the OleDB adapter and open/parse it as a standard text file.

Answer (score 0):

If the format of the generated file is likely to change in future (perhaps when you upgrade the third-party app), you may prefer to use the [Office Primary Interop Assemblies](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=59DAEBAA-BED4-4282-A28C-B864D8BFA513&displaylang=en). These will load any version or format of file produced by Excel. The downside is that you'll need Office installed on the server.

Comment: ... and the other downside is that server-side automation of Office is unsupported, not scalable, and has a number of problems including those described here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Comment: Who said it was running as a service?

Answer (score -1):

i solved the problem. The Excel file should be generated by MS EXCEL 2003, not from MS EXCEL 2007 "save as 97-2003".
so you have to download a file from any source. Then copy the data manually to the sheet. it worked with me.

Answer (score -2):

**Error**

```
[OleDbException] External table is not in the expected format.   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
```

**Solution**

I have faced above error in server side application.When you accessing many excel files at same time you can get this error.I have missed `connection.close()` and `connection.dispose()` methods in my code. After adding this code issue got resolved.
In catch block also you can add this code for safe side. `connection.open()` and `connection.dispose()` methods are mandatory for `Oledb` connection.