# How can I do this "select * from [sheet1$] where column is L" in Excel using OLEDB for C#?

Tags: c#, excel, console-application

I had asked about this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488403/how-to-iterate-through-a-column-in-an-excel-application-through-c-console) before but since the requirements changed, I am going to seek for answers again.

I am trying to get all of the contents within the L column of Excel or anything under the DocumentNo heading, which by the way is placed 7 cells below the first row. So the DocumentNo data is at L:7. It is followed by a blank cell, then cells of document numbers. I want to get all of the document numbers and place it in an array to be used in succeeding functions.

Help on this please.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a range modifier to tell it where to go

For example if you want just L column in your example

```
SELECT DocumentNo
FROM [sheet1$L7:Ll40]
```

This is assuming that the document numbers end at L140.

Comment: You can even have `FROM [sheet1$L:L]`

Comment: I had another problem and found this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200878/problem-parsing-an-xls-file-with-c/200946#200946

Answer (score 0):

```
   try          
        {      
            //Create a OLEDB connection for Excel file    
            string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +  
                "Data Source=" + "d:\\data.xls" + ";" +  
                "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";   
            OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString); 
            objConn.Open();               
            // Creating a command object to read the values from Excel file   
            OleDbCommand ObjCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT DocumentNo FROM [Sheet1$]", objConn);  
            // Creating a Read object             
            OleDbDataReader objReader = ObjCommand.ExecuteReader();  

            // Looping through the values and displaying   

            //if (objReader.

            while (objReader.Read())       
            {

                object obj = objReader["DocumentNo"];

            }                
            //Disposing the objects  
            objReader.Dispose();   
            ObjCommand.Dispose();  
            objConn.Dispose();     
        }         
        catch (Exception ex)     
        {            
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
        }
```